# Há algum substituto para o _outp, removido no Visual C++ 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, input-output

Estou migrando um projeto em MFC do Visual Studio 2010 para o 2015.

Nesse processo descobri que [o _outp, dentre outros comandos, foram removidos permanentemente.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb531344.aspx)

No [MSDN (_outp, _outpw, _outpd)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/733szwah.aspx) informa que "Essas funções são obsoletas. A partir do Visual Studio 2015, eles não estão disponíveis no CRT." mas não indica nada que possa substituí-los. Gostaria de saber o que posso utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que sua única alternativa seja migrar o código usando as APIs suportadas:
 [Serial Communications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ff802693.aspx)